# Google Contacts error "Missing resource version ID"

Tags: google-contacts-api

Ok, things are starting to work for me. But, now I'm trying to update a contact, and am getting the "Missing resource version ID" message. Steps:

1) retrieve the contact via API - success
2) update values in the contact
3) write out an xml file with new "entry" - xml validates
4) try to do PUT, and I get the error.

The put command I'm using:

```
curl -s --request PUT \
        --header If-Match: * \
        --header "Content-Type: application/atom+xml" \
        --header "Depth: 0" \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer <auth code> \
        --data-binary @/tmp/GooglePut0AGQzE \
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/4375e4498ef0b274
```

The xml is:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
       xmlns:batch="http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch"
       xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008" 
       xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" 
              term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/base/4375e4498ef0b274</id>
    <gContact:externalId label="enduser_acnt" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#customer" value="6006533" />
    <gd:name><gd:givenName>Dwayne</gd:givenName><gd:familyName>Johnson</gd:familyName></gd:name>
    <title type="text">Andy Wallace</title>
    <content type="text">Hello</content>
    <gd:organization rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other">
        <gd:orgName>iHOUSEweb, Inc</gd:orgName>
        <gd:orgTitle>Engineer</gd:orgTitle>
    </gd:organization>
    <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true">
        <gd:street>100 Smell St</gd:street>
        <gd:city>Smellville</gd:city>
        <gd:region>CA</gd:region>
    </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
    <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" address="awallace@ihouseweb.com" primary="true" />
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home" primary="true" >333-444-3333</gd:phoneNumber>
    <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" >222-333-4444</gd:phoneNumber>
</entry>
```

Any suggestions on what the error means? I have tried stripping out various bits of the data, specifying/not specifying the "If-Match: *" header, but nothing seems to turn the tide.

thanks,
andy

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found my problem. I was using the "If-Match" header wrong. Doh...

```
curl -s --request PUT \
         --header "If-Match: *" \
         --header "Content-Type: application/atom+xml" \
         --header "Depth: 0" \
         --header "Authorization: Bearer <auth key>" \
         --data-binary @/tmp/GooglePutwAdE69 \
         https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/4375e4498ef0b274
```

thanks dumbgamergirl, pointed my brain in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Add the if-match header field, and make sure that you are running your API with the latest version.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Thanks, tried the if-match header - note my curl command above, or am I doing that incorrectly? I'm not using an API, just driving the Google API directly with exec-ing curl commands